# Не работает код: ошибка - SyntaxError: bad input on line 82

Tags: python, разработка-игр, if, pygame

```
import pygame
WIDTH = 640
HEIGHT = 360
FPS = 30
RBG = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
LightGray = (215, 215, 215)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
screen.fill(RBG)

B = pygame.image.load('Background.jpg')
NL = pygame.image.load('NinjaLeft.png')
NR = pygame.image.load('NinjaRight.png')
KL = pygame.image.load('KunaiLeft.png')
KR = pygame.image.load('KunaiRight.png')
SL = pygame.image.load('SurikenLeft.png')
SR = pygame.image.load('SurikenRight.png')
SB = pygame.image.load('StartButton.png')
IB = pygame.image.load('InstructionButton.png')

B = pygame.transform.scale(B, (640, 360))
NL = pygame.transform.scale(NL, (120, 120))
NR = pygame.transform.scale(NR, (120, 120))
KL = pygame.transform.scale(KL, (45, 23.1))
KR = pygame.transform.scale(KR, (45, 23.1))
SL = pygame.transform.scale(SL, (22.5, 22.5))
SR = pygame.transform.scale(SR, (22.5, 22.5))
SB = pygame.transform.scale(SB, (320, 187))
IB = pygame.transform.scale(IB, (320, 187))

screenForm = 1

IBw = 320
IBh = 187
SBw = 320
SBh = 187

def menu():
    screen.blit(B, (0,0))
    screen.blit(IB, (WIDTH/2-IBw/2,HEIGHT/2-30))
    screen.blit(SB, (WIDTH/2-SBw/2,HEIGHT/2-130))
def instruction():
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.rect \
    (screen, LightGray, pygame.Rect(10, 10, 20, 2))
    pygame.draw.rect \
    (screen, LightGray, pygame.Rect(10, 15, 20, 2))
    pygame.draw.rect \
    (screen, LightGray, pygame.Rect(10, 20, 20, 2))

menu()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

pygame.display.update()

while running :
    clock.tick(FPS)
    
    mouseX = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
    mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]

    if screenForm == 1:
        menu()
        if (mouseX >= WIDTH/2-123) \
        and (mouseY <= HEIGHT/2+97.5) \
        and (mouseX <= WIDTH/2+123) \
        and (mouseY >= HEIGHT/2+30):
            IBw = 336
            IBh = 196.35
    
        elif (mouseX >= WIDTH/2-123) \
        and (mouseY <= 178) \
        and (mouseX <= WIDTH/2+123) \
        and (mouseY >= 108):
            SBw = 336
            SBh = 196.35
                                                                             
        else:
            IBw = 320
            IBh = 187
            SBw = 320
            SBh = 187
    SB = pygame.transform.scale(SB, (320, 187))
    IB = pygame.transform.scale(IB, (IBw, IBh))

    
        if screenForm == 2:
            instruction()
    
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if screenForm == 1:
                    if (mouseX >= WIDTH/2-123) \
                    and (mouseY <= HEIGHT/2+97.5) \
                    and (mouseX <= WIDTH/2+123) \
                    and (mouseY >= HEIGHT/2+30):
                        screenForm = 2
            
                if screenForm == 2:
                    if (mouseX >= 10) and (mouseY <= 22) \
                    and (mouseX <= 30) and (mouseY >= 10):
                        screenForm = 1
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: А что находится на 82 строке?

Comment: elif (mouseX >= WIDTH/2-123) \ и тд

Comment: Как вы код запускаете? У меня он никаких ошибок синтаксиса не показывает, при старте только показывает ошибки, что должны быть целые числа вместо float, например в `KL = pygame.transform.scale(KL, (45, 23.1))`

Comment: Вставил ваш код в PyCharm, той ошибки нет. Код выполняется, но пришлось пути к картинкам поменять. А после попал на ошибку в `KL = pygame.transform.scale(KL, (45, 23.1))` `TypeError: integer argument expected, got float`, но она должна была позже у вас произойти. Вообще ошибка `SyntaxError: bad input on line 82` происходят до выполнения кода интерпретатором